# JavaFX 2 and Linux

Tags: java, javafx-2

**JavaFX 2** is not support **Linux** yet. Does this mean a **client** Linux machine (user machine) cannot run it or a **server** Linux machine (host machine) cannot run it or both?

****EDIT:****

JavaFX is for rich client. So the server will not run it, but store it and client will get it and run it, right?

Comment: Adobe Air stop developing further for Linux. I am thinking like you if JavaFX2 will be stoped for Linux too!!!!!!!

Comment: JavaFX 2 for Linux is listed in the roadmap for 2012: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can't use the JavaFX libraries on a machine running Linux.  Neither a client Linux machine, nor a server Linux machine can use them.

**Response to Edit**

You can still *store* and *serve* JavaFX code on Linux machines.  You just can't *execute* the JavaFX code on a Linux machine.

Note that JavaFX is different from Java.  You can still use Java on Linux machines.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFx depends on hardware acceleration to run. This is currently not supported on linux (expected 2012). So if your server is executing JavaFx code, then it would not run on the server. If it is only delivering code to clients, like in an applet, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was posed a while back (11/2011), but I thought it might help to point out the related Open Source project from the OpenJDK community called [OpenJFX](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/).  Feel free to help out with development, if you're qualified to do so as well.  Given the secure nature of Linux, this project should prove a secure/safe way to utilize the "hardware acceleration to run"; though, it's still in the development stages.

Take a look at the project wiki to learn [how to build OpenJFX on Linux](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX#BuildingOpenJFX-LinuxDesktopBuildLinux).